# add a new dropdown to the product edit form, he data should come from a custom table I created magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, module

I want to add a new dropdown to the product edit form in magento2. The data should come from a custom table I created in a custom module. How do I do this, is there a good example or tutorial out there?

Comment: you can create product drop-down attribute and update its values in back-end instead to create separate table.